# NextJS Jest Environment issue when testing a component

Tags: next.js, jestjs, next-auth, ts-jest

He team, hope your days are going well!

I'm writing a NextJS application with a server side component using getServerSession, and it works great in the browser, but when testing it with Jest I'm getting an error caused by the jest-environment like so:
Details:

```
/Users/harryboyes/dev/ascendit/node_modules/jose/dist/browser/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { compactDecrypt } from './jwe/compact/decrypt.js';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

   7 | import CreateGymLink from "@/app/gyms/components/CreateGymLink";
   8 |
>  9 | jest.mock("next-auth");
```

The suggested solution is to use @jest-environment node, which solves the problem for my Server Actions but when testing a Component I get the error:
The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined

  16 |
  17 |     test("Doesn't render the button", async () => {
> 18 |       render(await CreateGymLink());
```

Does anyone have any experience in writing unit tests to test getServerSession in a component? Or any ways to work around this issue? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!